# Paraphrase of "all of life has been a farce", etc

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

> In her collection of short stories, “Homesick for Another World,” a little girl is convinced that a hole will open up in the earth and take her straight to paradise, if only she murders the right person. These characters share with their creator an intense sense of alienation, which she wrote about in a faux letter to Donald Trump: “**Since age five, all of life has been like a farce, an absurd performance of a reality based on meaningless drivel, or a devastating experience of trauma and fatigue, deep with meaning, which has led me into such self-seriousness that I often wonder if I am completely insane. Can you relate at all?”**
>
> <sub>*The New Yorker*, [Ottessa Moshfegh’s Otherworldly Fiction](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/07/09/ottessa-moshfeghs-otherworldly-fiction) By Ariel Levy</sub>

Can you please paraphrase the section in bold? I tried myself but I am not sure if  I am correct.

My assumption:

> Since I was a 5-year-old child the world and what was streaming in it everyday was farce (very funny ha ha for me and at the same time disturbing) and like some theater that was based on reality and since the reality itself was full of drivel the adopted theater also became like a drivel! Sometimes I doubt if I am really insane in such atmosphere? Can you even repeat what I said?

Does “relate” mean repeat here? Or means make a connection and then make a decision?

Comment: Please read through the [Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783) on meta, and pay particular attention to the parts about putting quoted material in a quote box (which is done with a single '>' character), and the part about **giving your question a title**. You should make quoted text easy to distinguish from your question about that material. Moreover, it's not good to have several questions that all have a title that says, "Can you paraphrase the highlighted part of the text please?" which gives no indication of what your question is really about.

Comment: You don't have a real question here. Checking if your paraphrase of a whole paragraph is right isn't a real question. What doesn't seem to make sense? What article/pronoun/adjective/etc. seems out of place? What sentence construction seems new or unnatural? Did you consult dictionaries on unfamiliar words? Answering questions like these will help you find what's bothering you and will help us help you get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I shall attempt to paraphrase the meaning of what, intentionally, is highly stylized hyperbole. For those who like intense self-dramatization, any paraphrase of meaning misses the point, which is that the author tries to demonstrate that she lives at extremes of emotional perception that do not appear, even to herself, to be normal.

> Since I was five, my life has been like either a silly, meaningless comedy or else a deeply meaningful tragedy. This dichotomy (between absurdity and pain) has led me into such a sense of my own seriousness that I wonder if I am insane. Can you understand that in a sympathetic way?<